# put modelsummary table onto beamer slide in quarto

Tags: pdf, quarto, beamer, modelsummary

I'm trying to make some beamer slides. I have run some regressions and want to put the results on a slide. I'm using modelsummary to do this, and the table will print in the console but I can't get it onto a slide. Does anyone have advice?

````
```{r results = 'asis'}
#| label: MainRegression


mod1 <- feols(AvgDailySales ~ POP + Months + TEMP + WKNDD|ID,cluster = c("ID"), data = R)

mod2 <- feols(AvgDailySales ~ POP + Months + TEMP + WKNDD
              +U:FTE4|ID,
              cluster = c("ID"), data = R)

mod3 <- feols(AvgDailySales ~ POP + Months + TEMP + WKNDD
              +U:FTE4+W:SkiAcre|ID,
              cluster = c("ID"), data = R)

mod4 <- feols(AvgDailySales ~ POP + Months + TEMP + WKNDD
              +U:FTE4+W:SkiAcre + U:W:FTE4:SkiAcre|ID,
              cluster = c("ID"), data = R)

modlist = list(mod1, mod2, mod3,mod4)


modelsummary(modlist,stars = c("*" = .1, "**" = .05, "***" = .001),
             coef_omit = c("Intercept"),fmt = 5,output = 'default')
```
````